# Rails console returns valid statement whereas test fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For a model defined with

```
belongs_to :municipal
validates  :name, presence: true
has_one    :gdstore, dependent: :destroy
```

in the console

```
Neighbourhood.new(name: 'red distrikt').valid?
=> false
Neighbourhood.new(municipal_id: 3272, name: 'red distrikt').valid?
=> true
```

but running this test

```
test "valid if name and municipal id defined" do
  neighbourhood = Neighbourhood.new(municipal_id: 3272, name: 'red distrikt')
  assert neighbourhood.valid?
end
```

returns

```
Failure:
NeighbourhoodTest#test_valid_if_name_and_municipal_id_defined [/Volumes/SJT/r/gd /test/models/neighbourhood_test.rb:20]:
Expected false to be truthy.
```

The db schema confirms:

```
create_table "neighbourhoods", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "municipal_id", null: false
```

so what is going on here?  Note: the reverse assertion also generates the error.  I do not expect the has-one to create invalidity, as it could have no gdstore ...

Answer (score 1):

All right...  there was not fixture for a `municipal` with `id: 3272`, thus the testing error.